# Change the order of the focused elements in final-form-focus

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-final-form

I'm using `final-form-focus` with `react-final-form` to focus on first error, if there are any validation errors on submit. I have a custom `react-select` component, so I'm using a custom findInput method like this:

```
const findInput = (inputs, errors) =>
  inputs.find(input => {
    const name = input.name || input.dataset.name;
    return name && getIn(errors, name);
  });

const getFormInputs = name => () => {
  if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    return [];
  }
  const form = document.forms[name];
  const inputs = form && form.length ? Array.prototype.slice.call(form) : []; // cast cheat to get from HTMLFormElement children to FocusableInput

  // So far this is just copy-pasted from final-form-focus.
  // It would return inputs here, but here is the magic:

  const selectFields = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-select]")
  );

  const allInputs = inputs.concat(selectFields);

  return allInputs;
};

const focusOnError = focusDecorator(getFormInputs("pay-form"), findInput);
```

My select component is wrapped in a div and focused using ref like this:

```
const SelectInput = ({
  input,
  meta,
  initialValue,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const selectRef = React.createRef();

  const setFocus = () => {
    selectRef.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="input-wrapper"
        tabIndex="0"
        data-select
        data-name={input.name}
        onFocus={setFocus}
      >
        <Select
          {...rest}
          ref={selectRef}
          onChange={value => input.onChange(value)}
          value={input.value}
          openMenuOnFocus={true}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But the select is only focused at the end of the line, after all other components. Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-on-error-w-react-select-8ljls?fontsize=14). Is there any way to change the order of the focused elements in the same way as they appear in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's not a way to set the `name` attribute on the `<input/>` via React-Select, but you *can* set the `id` via `innerId`.

[image: Edit focus on error w/ react-select]